# How to search an array of PSobjects for a specific objects key using PSv2

Tags: arrays, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have an array of Objects.  I want to search the array to determine if the a specific value exists in $obj.NewName.  If the value is unique, then put the value in $obj.NewName.  If it does exist, increment value and search again until the value is unique.

```
Function CreateObject ($origionalName)
{
    $newName = $null
    $obj = $null

    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name OrigionalName -Value $origionalName
    $obj | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name NewName -Value $newName
    Return ($obj)
}

Function Get-NewPatchName ($patch)
{
    $patch.OrigionalPatchName.split("-") | Foreach {
        ## Pipelined string is $_.  Check if it starts with "KB".
        If ($_.substring(0,2) -like "kb" ) 
        {
            ## This create the new name based on the substring containing "KB...", and adds the existing file extension.
            $tempName = $_

            ## If there is a version number in the original file name, include that in the new name
            If ($patch.OrigionalPatchName -like "*-v*") 
            {
                $intPosition = ($patch.OrigionalPatchName.ToUpper()).IndexOf("-V")
                $tempName += ($patch.OrigionalPatchName.substring($intPosition+1,2))
            }

            ## Determine if name is unique
            {
                ## STUCK HERE!!!!!!!!!!
            }
        }
    }
}

$patchList = @()
$nameList = "AMD64-all-windows6.0-kb2900986-x64_63", `
            "AMD64-all-windows6.0-kb3124275-x64_57", `
            "AMD64-all-windows6.0-kb2900986-x64_63" 

Foreach ($name in $nameList){
    $patchList += CreateObject $name }

Foreach ($patch in $patchList) {
    Get-NewPatchName $patch }

Foreach ($patch in $patchList) {
    Write-Host "Origional Patch Name: " $patch.OrigionalName
    Write-Host "New Patch Name      : " $patch.NewName
}
```

Expected results:

```
Origional Patch Name:  AMD64-all-windows6.0-kb2900986-x64_63
New Patch Name      :  kb2900986
Origional Patch Name:  AMD64-all-windows6.0-kb3124275-x64_57
New Patch Name      :  kb3124275
Origional Patch Name:  AMD64-all-windows6.0-kb2900986-x64_63
New Patch Name      :  kb2900986a
```

I would process $origionalName down to it's kb#, Example:

```
$tempName = "kb2900986"
```

Then I want to see if $tempName already exists in patchList under any $patch.newName.  If it does, then I would increment the $tempName to

```
$tempName = "kb2900986a"
```

and run the search again.  Once $tempName is unique

```
$patch.newName = $tempName
```

I already figured out how to process and increment the $tempName.  I'm just stuck on how to search the $patchList to determine if the $tempName currently exists for any $patch.newName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm working under the assumption you are using a newer version of PS, this **WILL NOT** work in PS2 as it makes use of a somewhat sloppy feature of newer versions of the shell that makes life much easier for the task you are tackling. code below would go in the area you've identified with the comments.

```
if($patchlist.newname -contains $tempname){
  *do whatever you need to do if the list already contains the name*
} else {
  *do whatever you need to do if the list doesn't contain the name*    
}
```

This makes use of a powershell feature that will automatically access the `.newname` property of each item in the `$patchlist` array and present it as it's own array of values when calling `$patchlist.newname` its an interesting array feature that was introduced in PS3 I believe.  I'd also make sure your function stays atomic by passing in patchlist(preferably with a different name) but that's not really necessary.

**The PS2 Version**

```
$templist = foreach($name in $patchlist){
  $name.NewName
}
if($templist -contains $tempname){
  *do whatever you need to do if the list already contains the name*
} else {
  *do whatever you need to do if the list doesn't contain the name*    
}
```

That will work for any version of powershell, it's not exactly optimized(creates the $templist array for each iteration) but it works and you can make changes as needed if you need additional speed

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for the update.  Unfortunately I do need to run this under PSv2.  I made the mistake of not even testing it on v2 yet.  Thanks.  I'll update the question to include the version number.  Do you know of a process that would work for v2?  Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "Make sure your function stays atomic".  Would you mind explaining that to me?

Comment: okk, you can do something similar with 2 but you'll need to create a temp array first, I'll edit my answer to reflect that.  and what I mean by that is you want to be able to pick up your function and drop it into another script without changing anything about the other script or your function, so rather than accessing global variable's from your script inside your function you should pass in everything that's needed as a parameter.  it also makes things a bit easier to read for someone coming along later.

Answer (score 0):

[Mike Garuccio's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41064272/45375) contains important pointers to the solution.

Here's an idiomatic PowerShell v2+ solution that also streamlines the code in the question:

```
# Convert an array of patch names to custom objects containing
# an .OriginalName property with the input patch name, and a yet-to-be-assigned
# .NewName property.
Function CreateObjects ([string[]] $originalNames)
{
  foreach ($name in $originalNames) {
    [pscustomobject] @{ OriginalName = $name; NewName = $null }
  }
}

# Assign a unique name to the .NewName property of all input objects.
Function Set-NewPatchNames ([pscustomobject[]] $patches)
{
    # Initialize an aux. hashtable in which we'll keep track of the unique 
    # new names assigned so far.
    $htNewNames = @{}
    foreach ($patch in $patches) {
      # Extract the KB number from the original name.
      # Note: For brevity, the "-v" version-number extraction mentioned in the 
      #       question is skipped. 
      $newNameCandidate = $patch.OriginalName -replace '.*-kb(\d+).*', '$1'
      # Is the candidate for the new name unique?
      if ($htNewNames.Contains($newNameCandidate)) { # Name already used.
        # Find a unique variation of the name.
        $rootName = $newNameCandidate
        # Loop and append 'a', 'b', ... until a unique name is found.
        # Note: With more than 26 duplicates, you'll run out of letters, 
        #       at which point seemingly random Unicode chars. will be used.
        $suffixCharCode = ([int] [char] 'a') - 1
        do {
          ++$suffixCharCode
          $newNameCandidate = $rootName + [char] $suffixCharCode
        } while ($htNewNames.Contains($newNameCandidate))
      }
      # Assign the new name and record it in the hashtable of names used so far. 
      $patch.NewName = $newNameCandidate
      $htNewNames.Add($newNameCandidate, $null)
    }
}

# The input list of patch names.
$nameList = "AMD64-all-windows6.0-kb2900986-x64_63",
            "AMD64-all-windows6.0-kb3124275-x64_57",
            "AMD64-all-windows6.0-kb2900986-x64_63" 

# Create a collection of custom objects with the original patch name
# stored in .OriginalName, and a yet-to-be-filled .NewName property.
$patchList = CreateObjects $nameList

# Fill the .NewName properties with unique names.
Set-NewPatchNames $patchList

# Output the resulting objects.
$patchList
```

In PSv5.1, this yields (the code *does* work correctly in PSv2, but yields slightly less readable output):

```
OriginalName                          NewName 
------------                          ------- 
AMD64-all-windows6.0-kb2900986-x64_63 2900986 
AMD64-all-windows6.0-kb3124275-x64_57 3124275 
AMD64-all-windows6.0-kb2900986-x64_63 2900986a
```